How does the Humean view of the laws of nature explain why objects behave according to laws?
The Humean view regarding the laws of nature is that laws are merely descriptions of the world. They merely describe, rather than prescribe, the behavior of objects that follow certain patterns.
But how does this view then explain why things follow patterns in the first place? More crucially, how does it explain why the objects continue to unbreakably follow patterns if the laws themselves are not prescribing their behaviour?

...was there anybody who ever put forward the notion that human beings prescribe the laws? of nature?

@CosmicGenis He meant (and explicitly said) Humean (with 'e' between 'm' and 'a'), not human. See this.

@user80226 When the author wrote "D.H. originated the story that laws are descriptions of the natural world", that presupposes that there was an earlier view that men prescribed the laws of nature. Because you don't originate a new story unless there's an already-existing story that needed refutation.


how does it explain why the objects continue to unbreakably follow patterns if the laws themselves are not prescribing their behaviour

It does not and does not claim to.

Does this mean that Humans posit these patterns as mere coincidences then?

@Syed, did you mean humans, or Humeans in the comment above?

@Syed They might not actively say they are coincidences, however they would say we have no way of identifying a cause or a reason to believe they will continue

How if things didn't follow the patterns? If nature broke our 'unbreakable' laws, would we accuse nature of being wrong or would we amend the laws?
